# how to started new project for spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My project name is colormanagment, this project developing started spring MVC.

So, I to create project and new controller configurations and view JSP file management location. Can anybody give sample example or example link means it's very useful for me.

Comment: examples of what? Where it your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provides a project as example. It is also mentioned in their documentation. So I advise you to take a look at this project :

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to some example on Spring MVC http://spring.io/blog/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/

And JavaBrains has some good Spring Video tutorials http://javabrains.koushik.org/spring.html

You can also download the springsource tool suite here http://spring.io/tools/sts/all then go to the file menu select new >> Spring Project >> Spring MVC Project. This is a simple spring MVC project with a Controller, XML configurations and a JSP view. I believe this a great starting point cause the application is simple and you can build with it as a foundation

Hope these help

Answer (score 1):

It is available in their documentation. You could also refer this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm